# Boostrap: How to "stick" a button over an image when re-sizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an image in which I need to put a button over, the problem is that I don't know how to place the button and automatically re-size and position it when making the browser smaller, right now I have the button in place, but when I re-size the browser to get smaller the button moves, I tried using percentages in the css buy doesn't work, what can I do?

```
<div id="discover" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid"> 
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 withimg">
    <img id="discoveryour" src="img/x.png" class="img-responsive">
  </div>  
</div>
<div class="row-fluid"> 
  <div id="bttnimg" class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
<form id="start" method="post" action="x.php">
<button class="btn-primary">text</button>
</form> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
  .withimg {
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
 }

  #discover{
  position: relative;  
 }

#bttnimg{
float: left;
position: absolute;
left: 62%;
top: 25%;
max-width: 750px;

 }
```

Comment: I think you should use JQuery for it.

Comment: @elunap You certainly could use JQuery to adjust button position and size, but it's not necessary. A little CSS will do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ah, the good old "how to overlay *stuff* on top of a responsive image -- responsively" question.

A little tricky, but not too bad. The tricky bit is how to make the *stuff's* vertical position responsive when the image size changes.

Fear not, here's one simple way to do this:

[image: responsive image with button]

HTML:

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img-responsive"
       src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-1200-400-4.jpg">
  <div class="img-overlay">
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-success">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-overlay:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  /* adjust 'height' to position overlay content vertically */
  height: 50%;
}
```

The `img-overlay:before` pseudo-class handles the vertical positioning job by pushing the `img-overlay` div down from the top of the image. In this example, the top of the button will always be 50% down the image (change the `height: 50%` attribute if you want the button higher or lower).

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/terrymorse/bt3pmubc/)

To make the button *size* responsive to window width, you can create a new class for your button. Let's call it `btn-responsive` (this replaces `btn-md` in the example above). Then use `@media` queries to adjust the `btn-responsive` attributes for different window widths. Something like this:

```css
.btn-responsive {
  /* matches 'btn-md' */
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

@media (max-width:760px) {
  /* matches 'btn-xs' */
  .btn-responsive {
    padding: 1px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
}
```

and so forth for other screen widths.

Comment: In some years from now, when we all are dead, I would be standing at St. Peter's door, and he would welcome me into Paradise, then of course he would ask me if I want to meet some one special, like Gandhi or maybe Mother Teresa, at that moment I would see him in the eyes and tell him, "thanks St. Peter, but I rather see some one who is actually a saint, take me with terrymorse, I need to high five this man". So yes, this was so well explained, and so good, thanks a lot!!!, I'll see you on the other side.

Comment: How can I adjust the button horizontally? Using width in the .img-overlay:before class doesn't work for me.

Comment: Nice choice of picture, adds dimension to anotherwise extremely good answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're wondering how to do this with bootstrap 5 (like me), there are new classes that do the trick. For instance, I did this to put a button floating right top over the image (I also use font-awesome but you can use any text/icon you like for the button):

```
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="someimage.png" alt="alt text">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm float-end"
           data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-content="Edit image" data-bs-trigger="hover focus">
            <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Some title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some text</p>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Check out [the official bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/#image-overlays) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask if there's a possibility to replace form tag into another DIV? Then you can just use `position: absolute` for button. I created fiddle to show how https://jsfiddle.net/1x1pjwk7/

Comment: Tried this, but the button still moves on re-sizing :/

Comment: @elunap did you resolved this issue? as I have the same issue I would like to find out

Comment: Yeah, check out the response of Terry Morse, it really helped my out