# position a <Link> over a background image

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this functional component:

```
    return (

    <div className={styles.parentDiv}>


        <div className={styles.divLink}>
            <Link className={styles.link}>
                some text
            </Link>
        </div>
    </div>

)
```

and this css:

```
.parentDiv {

    height: 70vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: url('../../assets/image.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.divLink {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    left: 10;

    height: 10; 
    width: 10;
    background-color: rgb(14, 7, 7); 
}

.link {  
}
```

My goal is to place some `react-router-dom <Link>` components on top of the background image so that they fit the image and if you resize your window, that the links still fit to the picture.

I tried this [Boostrap: How to "stick" a button over an image when re-sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647044/boostrap-how-to-stick-a-button-over-an-image-when-re-sizing/35676474) but it is more bootstrap related and also not covering the topic with a background image.

I also tried many other things but I just don't get it right. E.g. I can't even position the `divLink` with the `position: absolute; top: 10; left: 10;` - it just doesn't do anything. However I put in on `position: relative; top: 10vh; left: 10vw;` it does do it. Why is this? So all in all I think I am missing here some more things...I am a little lost to be honest.

And also even though that is a second question but related:
Is there a tool to support with css files and such alike? I always spent so much time in layouting because I run in issues like this one or others even simpler ones...

Answer (score 0):

I have created one [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voxgtr2m/3/)

```
.parentDiv {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492__480.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.divLink {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    left: 10;

    height: 10;
    width: 10;
    background-color: red; 
}
```

Is this something you are looking for?
You can modify accordingly with yours.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. However it does not solve my problem. Also in the fiddle I can't set the position of the link with `top` or `left`. Does it work for you? Lets say in the fiddly I want to have `some text` on top of the center of the flower and it should be responsive and resize accordingly.